# Change HTML output of Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, decorator

I'm trying to change the html outputted by Zend_Form using decorators.

I want the outputted HTML to look like this:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Your Details</legend>
    <dl>
    <dt>label etc</dt>
    <dd>input etc</dd>
    <dt>label etc</dt>
    <dd>input etc</dd>
    </dl>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Address Details</legend>
    <dl>
    <dt>label etc</dt>
    <dd>input etc</dd>
    <dt>label etc</dt>
    <dd>input etc</dd>
    ... etc ...
    </dl>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I've already broken the sections down i want within specific fieldsets using display groups, e.g.

```
$this->addDisplayGroup(array('name','email','telephone'),'yourdetails');
$yourdetails= $this->getDisplayGroup('personal');
$yourdetails->setDecorators(array(
            'FormElements',
            'Fieldset'
));
```

This gives me each section sitting within a fieldset but each form element is now lacking a wrapping dl so what i have is:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
    <dt>label etc</dt>
    <dd>input etc</dd>
    <dt>label etc</dt>
    <dd>input etc</dd>
    </fieldset>
    ... etc
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$yourdetails->setDecorators(array(
            'FormElements',
            array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dl')),
            'Fieldset'
));
```

That should:

1. Iterate through the elements
2. Add a `<dl>` around the group of elements
3. Add a `<fieldset>` around the `<dl>`