# Zend Framework - wrap dt dd in dl

Tags: php, zend-framework

From another question in [Change HTML output of Zend_Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148406/change-html-output-of-zend-form) does anyone know how I can produce the following html output? (Wrap each dtdd sets with dl)

```
<form>
<fieldset>
   <dl>
      <dt>label etc</dt>
      <dd>input etc</dd>
   </dl>
   <dl>
      <dt>label etc</dt>
      <dd>input etc</dd>
   </dl>
</fieldset>
... etc
</form>
```

Comment: If you change the markup, please change it in a way that has some MEANING :( Starting a list for a single entry is no good

Comment: Really nobody knows how to this?

Comment: @ChipZend I have an answer for you ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you are:

```
class Default_Form_Chip extends Zend_Form
{

    protected $_element_decorators = array(
        'ViewHelper',
        array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' => 'form_element')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'dt', 'class' => 'required', 'tagClass' => 'form_label')),
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'dl', 'class' => 'form_wrapper')),
    );

    //put your code here
    public function init()
    {
        $this->setElementDecorators($this->_element_decorators);
        $this->setDecorators(array(
            'FormElements',
            array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'fieldset')),
            'Form',
        ));
        $this->addElement('text', 'username',array(
            'label'=>'Username'
        ));
        $this->addElement('text', 'password',array(
            'label'=>'Password'
        ));
    }

}
```

Output html:

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <dl class="form_wrapper">
            <dt id="username-label">Username</dt>
            <dd class="form_element">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="">
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <dl class="form_wrapper">
            <dt id="password-label">Password</dt>
            <dd class="form_element">
                <input type="text" name="password" id="password" value="">
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: That's just what I needed. Thanks a lot, eureka!

Comment: :aces: :) yes, `'data' => '` Note: the key "data" can be anything. e.g. `array(array('elements' => 'HtmlTag'), ...` and then the next one `array(array('wrap' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dl', 'class' => 'form_wrapper')), ...`